# Horizontal dropdown menu with vertical

Tags: html, css, navigation, submenu

I'm trying to modify a template navigation bar to have a dropdown on 
`how-to` hover, but I can't seem to get `sub 2` to drop below `sub 1`.

I also noticed that things break when put to mobile size and is hovered. (but that's because I haven't worried about the mediascreen yet).

Any ideas?

[**See the fiddle for the full code.**](https://jsfiddle.net/m7tnf8ao/)

HTML

```
<!-- Navigation options -->
<nav class="clearfix">
    <ul class="clearfix">

        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">How-to</a>
<ul id="submenu">
<li><a href="#">sub1</a>
<li><a href="#">sub2</a>
</ul> <!--end sub ul-->
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Icons</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Web 2.0</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>  
    </ul> <!-- end ul clearfix -->
    <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
</nav> <!-- end nav clearfix -->
```

CSS

```
.clearfix li:hover ul {
display: block;
}

.clearfix li ul {
display: none;
position: absolute;
top:100%;
background: #455868;
width: auto;
height: auto;
vertical-align: top;
}

.clearfix li ul li {
width: auto;
}

.clearfix li ul a {
display: block;
}
```

**For full code see Fiddle:**
https://jsfiddle.net/m7tnf8ao/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your submenu `li` elements were picking a float from `nav li` rule.

Added on line 38 in jsfiddle:

```
.clearfix li ul li {
  width: auto;
  float:none; /* <- this one here */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To make sub 2 apear under sub1 turn off float property for sub menus:

```
#submenu li {
  float: none;
}
```

Second problem solved with:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #submenu {
    position: static;
  }
}
```